# MAMP $PATH issue

Tags: php, path, terminal, mamp, homebrew

I tried to install imagemagick on MAMP using some of the suggestions on Stack, and it seems I have broken MAMP. The start page loads up find but when I try to go to my site I get no response. Im only guessing it might be a $PATH problem, I really have no idea-- at this point Ive modified it so much I feel like I just screwed it up further. I really appreciate any help.

These are my steps into darkness:

Installed home brew

Installed ImageMagick

Modified $PATH

If I echo $PATH I get:

```
 /usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

If I run brew doctor I get:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
   <list of files>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - sortof. I removed home brew and that fixed the problem, however it was probably something to do with the /usr/local folder. The world may never know.